# Show that if $M^n$ is a smooth manifold and $A,B$ are closed disjoint sets on $M$ then there is a smooth function $ 0\le f \le 1$

Tags: proof-verification, differential-topology

Show that if $M^n$ is smooth a manifold and $A,B$ are closed disjoint sets on $M$ then there is a smooth function $ 0\le f \le 1$ with $f(A) = 0$ and $f(B) = 1.$

What I am trying is:

Note that $X-A$ is open, as well $X-B.$ In particular, $X - A \cap X - B = \emptyset$ and $X - A \cup X - B = X.$

Lets define $U = X - A$ and $V = X - B.$ Then there is a unity partition subordinated to this cover. By properties of unity partition, $\{f_U,f_V\}$, $f_U(A) = 0$ and $f_V(B) = 0.$ Even more, $f_A$ and $f_B$ are smooth. So, we can then define $g(x) = \frac{f_U(x)}{f_V(x) + f_U(x)}$. Then this is the searched function. Indeed, $0 \le g(x) \le 1$ and $g(A) = 0$, $g(B) = 1.$

Is this right?

Comment: I think it's right.. but $M$ has to be a smooth manifold.

Comment: @PeterFranek, yes! I am supposing this! I am sorry. Thanks!

Comment: @TsemoAristide, yes! But it is just about continuity, right?